# EF Gives Odd Property Names in Entity

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I've created a Companies table with foreign key (`ParentCompaniesId`) to the primary key of the same table.

When I generate an Entity Framework model from the database, it adds a `ParentCompany` property, just as I want. However, it also adds a collection property called `Companies1` to represent the many side of this same relationship.

Why `Companies1`? Is there any way to have it name this property `Companies` instead?

My table is similar to the one scripted below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Companies](
    [CompaniesId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentCompaniesId] [int] NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Companies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CompaniesId] ASC
)
WITH
(
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Companies]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Companies_Companies] FOREIGN KEY([ParentCompaniesId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Companies] ([CompaniesId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Companies] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Companies_Companies]
GO
```

Comment: Why don't you rename it to `ChildCompanies`, it will make more meaningful relationship?

Comment: @Jayantha: Well, I really don't see how that is more meaningful. The app has the concept of companies and parent companies, so I'm modeling that. But even if I did change the name, that wouldn't solve the problem. I could still have the funky name on the other side of the relationship.

Comment: Then why don't you just rename it in the designer (assuming you are using model first) ?

Comment: @Jayantha: Because then everytime I rebuild the model, wouldn't I have to do it again?

Comment: I really don't  understand here. You can right click in the navigation property an go to properties and set  the name.

Comment: And what happens when I rebuild the model from the database?

Comment: Are you doing `Model First` or `Database First` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3762/discussion-between-jayantha-and-jonathan-wood)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug in the designer - actually the only thing in conceptual model I'm aware of which doesn't survive update from database. There is not much to do with this. You can use simple script / app. which will be run manually after *Update from database* to replace all these unexpected names with expected one. You can also give up with *Update from database* and maintain EDMX manually (it is XML file).

Comment: I've run into this & it is annoying.  I've been meaning to write a script to fix up the names -- if anyone has an example they would like to share, it would be appreciated.